# Batch: % in file name

Tags: batch-file

I think this is a simple batch programming question, but after much searching, I can't find the answer.

I'm trying to figure out how to refer to files whose names contain difficult characters.

It seems that double quotes have the effect of treating most enclosed characters literally. For example, for a file named ^^.txt, dir "^^.txt" will find the file, while dir ^^.txt won't.

However, I don't know how to escape %. For example, for a file named %ERRORLEVEL%.txt, none of these find the file:

dir "%ERRORLEVEL%.txt"
dir "%%ERRORLEVEL%%.txt"
dir "^%ERRORLEVEL^%.txt"

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @KenWhite, actually you can.  Try `echo >^%ERRORLEVEL^%.txt`.

Comment: @KenWhite, not true: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions).

Comment: Ah, I thought it was in the list of invalid chars like `:` and `<`. I stand corrected. :-)

Comment: `%` is legal in file names, see `Alcohol 120%`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The escape character for the Windows command prompt is `^`.  It works without the quotes.

```
dir ^%errorlevel^%.txt
```

For your other example `^^.txt`, use:

```
dir ^^^^.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Can you use ^ to escape spaces? For example, for a file named "Hello world.txt", dir Hello^ world.txt doesn't seem to find the file. Here, I could use quotes with dir, but what if the file name has both % and spaces?

Comment: Use quotes when there are spaces.  The `%` just works.  so `dir "%error level%.txt"` works.  Files that I couldn't delete without a batch file are ones with valid environment variables AND spaces, like `%errorlevel% %date%.txt`.  A batch file using `del "%%errorlevel%% %%date%%.txt" would work.

Comment: @mdb - Technically that is not escaping the `%` expansion. Variable expansion looks for variable named `errorlevel^`, but when if fails to find it, it simply preserves the `%`s (command line only). The carets are stripped prior to the actual execution of the DIR command. If variable `errorlevel^` exists, it would be expanded by `%errorlevel^%`. The caret could appear anywhere between the percents. For example, `%error^level%` works just as well from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Always avoid % and ^ in filenames.  Rename % to 'percent' in a global file manager.

```
They are next to impossible to handle properly in many batch commands.
```

Answer (score 0):

In a batch script you must double the `%`, eg.:

```
@echo off 
dir %%errorlevel%%.txt
```

Btw. you should not use cmd default variable or command names for other things (errorlevel).